# OpenCV Cpp code not running in Ubuntu 20.04 after update

Tags: c++, opencv

I have updated my ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 20.04.

Earlier my cpp code of OpenCV was running perfectly but now it is showing the following output on the terminal every time.

[image: Error]

Below these errors, there are "undefined reference" errors also.

Please help me out with this error message.

To check the OpenCV version installed in my PC:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv4
>>> 4.3.0
```

Comment: Does it still compile ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, I don't think so. This is the error message coming and no a.out file is created in the directory.

Comment: Did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915966/unknown-gcc-linker-error-but-builds-sucessfully) ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, The warning seems to be the same but I am not able to figure out what to do with your link also. Also, if it is just a warning, then why no a.out file is created?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I noticed that when I try to compile this program, for a second a.out file is created and then it gets removed automatically with this error message being printed on the terminal.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your code since updating Ubuntu?

Comment: @AlanBirtles No,  but I have created a new sample code which simply reads the image and shows it. For that also the same error message is coming.